# How to restrict the application endpoint from loading in a browser?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams

I am trying to develop a teams messaging extension using ASP.NET core 3.1. The application is hosted on Azure app service. I want the app to be loaded within teams, but not on the browser. Now I'm able to load the application on browser by providing the app url, which must not happen.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your ask?

Comment: @Sangeetha - Once you develop Messaging Extension and integrate it in Teams, You can open the ME from Teams Desktop client and from Browser client as well.
You can not restrict it.
Is this clarify your issue or looking for any other input?

Comment: The ME should open from within teams desktop client as well as the teams browser client. But in my case, the ME is hosted as an application on App service.  The app service needs to be configured to respond only if the requests are originating from teams client. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Sangeetha - I hope you have created ME with bot and deployed it to App Service?

Comment: @Sangeetha - I think, we can not configure the app service to restrict ME from accessing outside of Teams client.
Hope you are following and developing similar kind of application:
doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions?tabs=dotnet

Sample link:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search

Comment: @Sangeetha - Please let us know if you need any other details here?

Answer (score 1):

As Suggested by [ChetanSharma-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16388338/chetansharma-msft) and as per this Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions?tabs=dotnet#scenarios-where-messaging-extensions-are-used) we cannot configure we app to restrict message extension.

Here are the few example scenarios where message extensions are used

[image]